What is Emily Norcross trying to say in this scene?
What is Emily Norcross trying to say in this scene from Dickinson S01E04? (Timestamp 23:20)

Emily Norcross: I held my legs together when he was trying to be born.
Lavinia Dickinson: Mom, What are you talking about ?
Emily Norcross: Because I was scared and your father wasn't home. So, I held my legs together a bit too long to keep him in there. I think now that may have been a mistake.

Why was holding him for a bit long a mistake? What is she trying to point out?

What she is trying to point out can't be deduced from this dialogue, so you have to provide more context. But I think this has more to do with a general understanding of the consequences of trying to prevent a baby from being born then it has with the interpretation of this specific scene from this specific series.

Emily's son William Austin Dickinson has just performed a poem he composed which, blatantly, was not very good.

"The wheels of destiny
Have run their course
Amherst is getting the iron horse
Yes, Amherst gets a train at last
We used to go slow,
but now we'll go fast
Through woods and hills
The train will romp
We'll build it a bridge
To get over the swamp
[JANE SCOFFS]
The train will carry all the people
Red-skinned savages and Negroes
[MURMURING]
So, I can't wait to ride the train
And after that I'll ride it again
Again"

Emily is indicating that his lack of ability could be considered due to an issue when he was born when she delayed his birth.
It's likely the story is an exaggeration and she's just making excuses for him in a somewhat comical fashion.
